# Can I represent large integers in Node 6 for only exponentiation without a dependency?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am working on a kata that asks for the last digit of `a[0] ^ (a[1] ^ (a[2] ^ ... (a[n-1] ^ a[n])))`. When computing the answer, eventually `Math.pow` exceeds `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, causing `modexp` below to return erroneous results.

[@user2357112 says that JS needs a library for arbitrary-precision integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36900456/394397), which is all well and good, but nothing in the kata indicates that such a library is available in the remote environment, or even that I need one.

Since the kata and SO point in different directions on this matter, I want to learn if I can feasibly represent big integers ONLY for the purposes of solving this kata without writing an entire library.

My in-progress code is below, and it passes many tests before printing incorrect results. <s>Some code was omitted to avoid spoilers.</s>

**TL;DR: If I cannot use a library, what can I do to feasibly represent large integers for the use case indicated by Math.pow()?**

```
function modexp(b, e) {
    let c = 1
    while(e) {
        if (e & 1)
            c = c * b % 10

        e >>= 1
        b = b * b % 10
    }

    return c;
}

function lastDigit(as) {
    if (!as || !as.length) return 1;

    let e = as.slice(1).reverse().reduce((p,c) => Math.pow(c,p));

    return modexp(as[0], Number(e));
}
```

Comment: Your task is to find the *last digit only*. You are not supposed to represent large integers; try not to use them, and you won't need a library.

Comment: There is no reason to include spoilers in your question. Please post your whole code.

Comment: @Bergi Unless I'm misunderstanding you, tests fail if I use modexp exclusively. The instructions specify finding the last digit of the final expression `a[0] ^ (a[1] ^ (a[2] ^ ... (a[n-1] ^ a[n])))`, not any intermediate values. I can't do `a[0] ^ (lastDigitOf(a[1]) ...)`

Comment: @Bergi Added the rest of the code as requested

Comment: Yes, you can't do exactly that, but the idea with modexp wasn't bad. Have a look at all the possible outcomes of `lastDigitOf(b ^ e)` for some fixed `b` and arbitrary `e`, and whether you really need to know `e` for that exactly or only certain properties of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously an X-Y problem. You don't need large integers.

You need to go back to elementary school math.

What's multiplication? Well let's take one example:

### WARNING: SPOILERS! Don't read the following if you want to figure it out yourself!

```
      1 2
   x  2 3
   ------
      3 6      last digit 6
    2 4
   ------
    2 7 6      notice how last digit is only involved
               in ONE multiplication operation?
```

Hmm.. there seems to be a pattern. Let's see if that pattern holds. Let's multiply `12 x 23 x 23` by only doing the last digit:

```
      1 2
   x  2 3
   ------
        6    calculate ONLY last digit
   x  2 3
   ------
        8    answer is: last digit is 8
```

Let's check our answer:

```
      1 2
   x  2 3
   ------
      3 6
    2 4
   ------
    2 7 6 
   x  2 3
   ------
    8 2 8
  5 5 2
  -------
  6 3 4 8    last digit is INDEED 8
```

So it seems that you can find the last digit by only calculating the last digit. Let's try to implement a `powLastDigit()` function.

### WARNING: SPOILERS! DON'T READ THE CODE IF YOU WANT TO WRITE IT YOURSELF!

```
function powLastDigit (number,power) {
    var x = number;

    for (var y=1; y<power; y++) {
        x = ((x%10)*(number%10))%10; // we only care about last digit!
    }

    return x;
}
```

Let's check if we are right:

```
> powLastDigit(3,7)
7
> Math.pow(3,7)
2187
> powLastDigit(5,8)
5
> Math.pow(5,8)
390625
> powLastDigit(7,12)
1
> Math.pow(7,12)
13841287201
```

OK. Looks like it's working. Now you can use this function to solve your problem. It has no issues with very large exponents because it doesn't deal with large numbers:

```
> powLastDigit(2323,123456789)
3
```

#### Optimization

The above code is slow because it uses a loop. It's possible to speed it up by using `Math.pow()` instead. I'll leave that as a homework problem.

Comment: There are [even better attempts](https://northrupanthony.wordpress.com/2016/09/02/last-digit-of-chain-exponentiation-part-2/) like this, but it is not a solution. It still fails for something like `powLastDigit(3, 4**5**6)`, because the argument `4**5**6` alone is too large.

Comment: @Bergi `powLastDigit(3,powLastDigit(4,powLastDigit(5,6)))`

Comment: That is not what the assignment (kata) asks for, no. And not a mathematically valid simplification either, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Bergi: Look at HIS code. He's doing it in a loop. He only needs a replacement of `Math.pow()`. The function above IS the replacement of `Math.pow()`, not the solution

Comment: Yes, one would need some kind of loop or recursion, but `powLastDigit` is *not* a replacement for `Math.pow` - it only can replace the outermost exponentation. In general, `powLastDigit(x, Math.pow(a, b)) != powLastDigit(x, powLastDigit(a, b))`

Comment: @Bergi: Hmm.. you're right. Need to think about this. Otherwise need to implement a simple largeInt implementation

Comment: I don't want to spoil you the fun of thinking about it, but I'm pretty sure you can do without largeints... Maybe I'll post an answer later.

Comment: @slebetman Thanks. I appreciate the throwback to basic arithmetic. Given incorrect output like `powLastDigit(0,0) === 0` and the fact that a quick unit test complains about the output for the last digit of `7 ^ (6 ^ 21)`, there's probably more to this. Will update question later.

Answer (score 0):

I use bit array to represent a positive integer;

```
[0,0,1,1] // bit array of 12 (MSB=rightmost)
```

This structure is used to manipulate the overall exponent, E

```
a[1] ^ (a[2] .. (a[n-1] ^ a[n])) // E
```

(!)There is a relation between `LSD(a[0])` and the overall exponent `E` as below

```
//LSD(a[0]) LSD(LSD(a[0]) ^ E) for 
//          [E/4R0, E/4R1, E/4R2, E/4R3]
//--------- ----------------------------
//        0 [0, 0, 0, 0]
//        1 [1, 1, 1, 1]
//        2 [6, 2, 4, 8]
//        3 [1, 3, 9, 7]
//        4 [6, 4, 6, 4]
//        5 [5, 5, 5, 5]
//        6 [6, 6, 6, 6]
//        7 [1, 7, 9, 3]
//        8 [6, 8, 4, 2]
//        9 [1, 9, 1, 9]
```

For example, find least significant digit of (2 ^ (2 ^ 3)),

```
// LSD(a[0]) is 2
// E is 8  
// implies E mod 4 is 0
// LSD(LSD(a[0]) ^ E) 
//     for E/4R0           is 6 (ans)
```

To determine `E mod 4`,

```
E[0] + E[1] * 2 // the two LSBs
```

To summarize, I create a data structure, bit array, to store large integers,
mainly for the intermediate value of exponent-part. The bit array is dynamic length obtaining max. 9007199254740991 bits, if all bits are set, the value in decimal is 2 ^ (9007199254740991 + 1) - 1. This bit array will never be converted back to decimal(safe). The only interesting information of overall exponent, E, is its two least significant bits, they are the remainder of E/4
which can be applied to the above relation(!).

Obviously, `Math.pow` will not work for bit array, so I handcraft a simple `exp()` for it. This is trivial since the fact that

```
//exponentiation == lots of multiplications == lots of additions
//it is not difficult to implement addition on bit array
```

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycw7788/q8mrcmma/) demonstrating above idea ONLY. It is intended to be slow if the E is really large. FYI

```
LSD.find([3,4,5,6])  // my Nightly hanged ~3s to find lsd
```

You may optimize the `Bits.exp` by means of childprocesses, web workers, debounce function, simd etc. Good luck.

Comment: This is the correct approach, but I think your table is wrong for the value 9

Comment: Do you mean the table of samples in the fiddle?

Comment: Nah, I meant `[1, 9, 1, 9]`, but I was mistaken. It's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a bigint library to solve this kata.

You are only interested in the last digit of the result, and fortunately there is a property of powers that helps us with this. We effectively want to compute a power in modulus 10. Yes, [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) does help us a bit here, but the problem is that the exponent is very large as well - too large to compute, and too large to run a loop with that many iterations. But we don't need to, all we are interested in is the modulus of the result.
And there is [a pattern](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/qq.09.04/landon1.html)! Let's take 4<sup>x</sup> as an example:

```
 x       4^x      (4^x)%10
--------------------------
 0   4^0  = 1     1
 1   4^1  = 4     4
 2   4^2  = 16    6
 3   4^3  = 64    4
 4   4^4  = 256   6
 5   4^5  = 1024  4
 …                …
20   4^20 = ???   6 sic!
21   4^21 = ???   4
 …                …
```

You will be able to find these patterns for all numbers in all modular bases. They all share the same characteristic: there's a threshold below which the remainder is irregular, and then they form a repeating sequence. To get a number in this sequence, we only need to perform a modulo operation on the exponent!
For the example above (`(4^x)%10`), we use a lookup table `0 → 6, 1 → 4` and compute `x % 2`; the threshold is `1`. In JavaScript code, it might look like this:

```
x < 1 ? 1 : [6, 4][x % 2];
```

Of course, `x` is a very large number formed by the repeated exponentiation of the rest of the input, but we do not need to compute it as whole - we only want to know

- whether it is smaller than a relatively small number (trivial)
- what the remainder after division by `q` is - just a recursive call to the function we're implementing!